# Tunneling from Windows 10 to Jupyter running on AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, putty, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to access Jupyter notebooks that are installed on AWS and I want to use a windows-10 machine to access it. The jupyter system sits behind a jump host (bastion) on aws. The process works for macs in the following way 
- Instructions exist to create a ssh tunnel
- Magically the notebook is available on a browser by doing localhost:8223
The mac command for it looks like

```
ssh -i /pathto.id_rsa -L 8223:<some name>:8223 -f -o <some other url>
```

What I've been able to accomplish is the following.
- Installed putty and pageant. Set up key forwarding on putty and been able to log in to the bastion host. 
- I tried foxyproxy on chrome but couldn't make much headway there.

How do I access this Jupyter notebook from windows?
Again, the set up is

```
windows --> [bastion] --> jupyter
```

I'm totally lost, any pointers or step by step instructions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this article from my blog: https://vrnchndk.in/2017/01/27/access-blocked-websites-using-ssh-tunnel/

It has step by step instructions with screenshots as well.